# Запрос на осутствие записи в смежной таблице в отношении многие ко многим

Tags: sql

У меня есть две сущности: кот и цвет. Они объединены связью многие-ко-многим:

```
create table cat (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar (100)
);

create table color (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar (100)
);

create table cat_color (
    cat_id integer references cat(id),
    color_id integer references color(id)
);
```

**Не могу понять как правильно сделать селект, который покажет всех котов с отсутствием серого (gray) цвета на шерсте.** Присутствие цвета находится достаточно просто:

```
select cat.name
from cat
join cat_color cc on cc.cat_id = cat.id
join color c on c.id = cc.color_id
where c.name = 'gray'
```

Судя по всему join'ы не помогут и понадобиться сделать дополнительный селект в селекте. Пока не совсем понимаю как он должен выглядеть.

Answer (score 0):

Да, делаем дополнительный селект.

```
select cat.name, color.name
from cat
join cat_color on cat_color.cat_id = cat.id
join color on color.id = cat_color.color_id
where cat.id not in
  (
    select cat.id
    from cat
    join cat_color on cat_color.cat_id = cat.id
    join color on color.id = cat_color.color_id
    where color.name = 'gray'
  )
```